# How to Aggregate Multiple Arrays to a Single Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have to call an endpoint multiple times and get the responses aggregated to a single array. Below is the response from the endpoint;

```
{
   items: [
      {key1: value},
      {key2: value}
   ]
}
```

Below is the code to call the endpoint multiple times;

```
const chunkedArray = getChunkedArray(largeArray);
const result = await Promise.all(
   chunkedArray.map(async (items) => {
      const response = await ....get(`http:/url/${items}`);
      return response.items;
   });
);
```

For the result I'm getting below;

```
[
   [
      {key1: value},
      {key2: value}
   ],
   [
      {key3: value},
      {key4: value}
   ]
]
```

What I want is an aggregated array like below;

```
[
   {key1: value},
   {key2: value},
   {key3: value},
   {key4: value}
]
```

What is the optimum way of doing that?

Comment: how you are appending the chunks to the final array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat);

```
let arr1 = [
   [
      {key1: value},
      {key2: value}
   ],
   [
      {key3: value},
      {key4: value}
   ]
]

let arr2 = arr1.flat(); 
/* [
      {key1: value},
      {key2: value},
      {key3: value},
      {key4: value}
   ] */
```

If you want to do it without flat you can use reduce too :

```
let promises = Promise.all(
   chunkedArray.map(async (items) => {
      const response = await ....get(`http:/url/${items}`);
      return response.items;
   });
);

const result =promises.reduce((cum,x) => {
let newArr = await x;
return [...cum,...newArr ];
},[]);
```